# Identify value change (categorical) by group. R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, lag

Below you can see a sample of my dataset.

```
Fac Date        Type        Change  StartDT     EndDT
AAA 1/1/2019    General     0   1/1/2019    1/2/2019
AAA 1/2/2019    General     0   1/1/2019    1/2/2019
AAA 1/3/2019    Special     1   1/3/2019    1/4/2019
AAA 1/4/2019    Special     1   1/3/2019    1/4/2019
AAA 1/5/2019    Intensive   2   1/5/2019    1/5/2019
BBB 1/1/2019    General     0   1/1/2019    1/4/2019
BBB 1/2/2019    General     0   1/1/2019    1/4/2019
BBB 1/3/2019    General     0   1/1/2019    1/4/2019
BBB 1/4/2019    General     0   1/1/2019    1/4/2019
BBB 1/5/2019    Reserve     1   1/5/2019    1/6/2019
BBB 1/6/2019    Reserve     1   1/5/2019    1/6/2019
```

I would like create a variable to track changes in my Type variable (change). I used to work in Stata and the logic to do this is to first track if the value change compared to the previous record (0/1) for each panel/group and then have a running sum of this value.

```
bysort Facility (Date): gen byte era = sum(Type != Type[_n-1] & _n > 1)
```

How can I do this in R? Also after change variable is created I will need to generate the start and end (min, max) dates for each Fac and Change ("era").

I would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!
Marvin

Comment: Please explain why change=2 here `AAA 1/5/2019    Intensive   2   1/5/2019    1/5/2019`

Comment: Because it went from Special to intensive. Any change in that variable should be track. So if facility AAA type would happen to change again, we would need to record it and it would be 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one solution, using dplyr:

```
dat =
  tibble(
    fac = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10)),
    type = sample(1:3, 20, replace = TRUE)
  )

dat %>% 
  group_by(fac) %>% 
  mutate(
    change = case_when(
      type != lag(type) ~ TRUE,
      TRUE ~ FALSE
    ),
    n_change = cumsum(change)
  )
```

For your code, you could then add:

```
group_by(Fac, n_change) %>%
mutate(
  min_start_date = min(StartDT),
  max_start_date = max(EndDT)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider iterating through sequence of row numbers with `sapply` to check between current and previous row's *Type* values. And use `ave` for inline aggregation of total by *Fac* group:

```
dat <- within(dat, {
  # CONVERT DATES
  Date <- with(dat, as.Date(Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"))
  StartDT <- with(dat, as.Date(StartDT, format="%m/%d/%Y"))
  EndDT <- with(dat, as.Date(StartDT, format="%m/%d/%Y"))

  # CALCULATE TYPE CHANGES
  type_delta <- c(NA, sapply(2:nrow(dat), function(i) 
                               ifelse(dat$Type[i] != dat$Type[i-1], 1, 0)
                             )
                 )
  era <- ave(type_delta, Fac, FUN=function(x) sum(x, na.rm=TRUE))
})

dat    
#    Fac       Date      Type Change    StartDT      EndDT era type_delta
# 1  AAA 2019-01-01   General      0 2019-01-01 2019-01-01   2         NA
# 2  AAA 2019-01-02   General      0 2019-01-01 2019-01-01   2          0
# 3  AAA 2019-01-03   Special      1 2019-01-03 2019-01-03   2          1
# 4  AAA 2019-01-04   Special      1 2019-01-03 2019-01-03   2          0
# 5  AAA 2019-01-05 Intensive      2 2019-01-05 2019-01-05   2          1
# 6  BBB 2019-01-01   General      0 2019-01-01 2019-01-01   2          1
# 7  BBB 2019-01-02   General      0 2019-01-01 2019-01-01   2          0
# 8  BBB 2019-01-03   General      0 2019-01-01 2019-01-01   2          0
# 9  BBB 2019-01-04   General      0 2019-01-01 2019-01-01   2          0
# 10 BBB 2019-01-05   Reserve      1 2019-01-05 2019-01-05   2          1
# 11 BBB 2019-01-06   Reserve      1 2019-01-05 2019-01-05   2          0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @Parfait and @user2363777 for all the help! This is amazing. I used user2363777 solution since I am more familiar with dplyr. For the last block of code I just included the ungroup() function at the end. Then I just keep one record per Facility and era.

```
Fac Era Type            StartDT     EndDT
AAA 0   General         1/1/2019    1/2/2019
AAA 1   Special         1/3/2019    1/4/2019
AAA 2   Intensive       1/5/2019    1/5/2019
BBB 0   General         1/1/2019    1/4/2019
BBB 1   Reserve         1/5/2019    1/6/2019
```

My ultimate goal is to generate a graph that depicts changes in facility types over time (change of a categorical variable over time). I am going to investigate how can I graph this. I may post something regarding this soon. Thank you!!