# Average duration of time spent R

Tags: r, loops, average, duration

I am trying to write a script that can calculate the average duration of behavioural events. Ideally something that will calculate for all my behavioural classes and if possible calculate standard error as well.

My data is as bellow

```
29/10/2015 6:09:38  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:09:39  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:09:40  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:09:41  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:09:42  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:09:43  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:09:44  9   Travel
29/10/2015 6:09:45  9   Travel
29/10/2015 6:09:46  9   Travel
29/10/2015 6:09:47  9   Travel
29/10/2015 6:09:48  9   Travel
29/10/2015 6:09:49  9   Travel
29/10/2015 6:09:50  9   Travel
29/10/2015 6:09:51  9   Travel
29/10/2015 6:09:52  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:09:53  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:09:54  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:09:55  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:09:56  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:09:57  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:09:58  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:09:59  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:00  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:01  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:02  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:03  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:04  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:05  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:06  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:07  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:08  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:09  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:10  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:11  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:12  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:13  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:14  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:15  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:16  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:17  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:18  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:19  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:20  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:21  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:22  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:23  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:24  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:25  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:26  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:27  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:28  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:29  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:30  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:31  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:32  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:33  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:34  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:35  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:36  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:37  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:38  9   Burst
29/10/2015 6:10:39  9   Burst
29/10/2015 6:10:40  9   Burst
29/10/2015 6:10:41  9   Burst
29/10/2015 6:10:42  9   Burst
29/10/2015 6:10:43  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:44  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:45  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:46  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:47  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:48  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:49  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:50  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:51  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:52  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:53  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:54  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:55  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:56  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:57  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:58  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:10:59  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:00  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:01  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:02  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:03  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:04  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:05  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:06  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:07  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:08  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:09  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:10  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:11  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:12  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:13  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:14  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:15  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:16  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:17  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:18  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:19  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:20  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:21  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:22  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:23  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:24  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:25  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:26  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:27  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:28  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:29  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:30  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:31  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:32  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:33  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:34  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:35  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:36  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:37  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:38  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:39  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:40  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:41  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:42  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:43  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:44  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:45  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:46  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:47  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:48  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:49  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:50  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:51  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:52  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:53  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:54  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:55  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:56  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:57  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:58  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:11:59  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:00  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:01  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:02  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:03  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:04  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:05  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:06  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:07  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:08  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:09  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:10  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:11  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:12  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:13  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:14  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:15  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:16  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:17  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:18  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:19  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:20  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:21  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:22  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:23  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:24  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:25  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:26  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:27  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:28  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:29  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:30  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:31  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:32  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:33  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:34  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:35  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:36  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:37  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:38  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:39  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:40  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:41  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:42  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:43  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:44  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:45  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:46  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:47  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:48  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:49  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:50  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:51  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:52  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:53  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:54  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:55  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:56  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:57  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:58  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:12:59  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:00  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:01  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:02  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:03  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:04  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:05  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:06  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:07  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:08  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:09  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:10  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:11  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:12  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:13  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:14  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:15  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:16  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:17  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:18  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:19  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:20  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:21  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:22  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:23  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:24  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:25  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:26  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:27  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:28  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:29  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:30  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:31  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:32  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:33  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:34  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:35  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:36  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:37  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:38  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:39  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:40  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:41  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:42  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:43  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:44  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:45  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:46  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:47  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:48  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:49  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:50  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:51  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:52  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:53  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:54  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:55  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:56  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:57  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:58  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:13:59  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:00  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:01  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:02  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:03  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:04  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:05  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:06  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:07  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:08  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:09  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:10  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:11  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:12  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:13  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:14  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:15  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:16  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:17  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:18  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:19  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:20  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:21  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:22  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:23  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:24  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:25  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:26  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:27  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:28  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:29  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:30  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:31  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:32  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:33  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:34  9   Burst
29/10/2015 6:14:35  9   Burst
29/10/2015 6:14:36  9   Burst
29/10/2015 6:14:37  9   Burst
29/10/2015 6:14:38  9   Burst
29/10/2015 6:14:39  9   Burst
29/10/2015 6:14:40  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:41  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:42  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:43  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:44  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:45  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:46  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:47  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:48  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:49  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:50  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:51  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:52  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:53  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:54  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:55  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:56  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:57  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:58  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:14:59  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:00  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:01  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:02  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:03  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:04  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:05  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:06  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:07  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:08  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:09  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:10  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:11  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:12  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:13  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:14  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:15  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:16  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:17  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:18  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:19  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:20  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:21  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:22  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:23  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:24  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:25  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:26  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:27  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:28  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:29  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:30  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:31  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:32  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:33  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:34  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:35  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:36  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:37  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:38  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:39  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:40  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:41  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:42  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:43  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:44  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:45  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:46  9   Travel
29/10/2015 6:15:47  9   Travel
29/10/2015 6:15:48  9   Travel
29/10/2015 6:15:49  9   Travel
29/10/2015 6:15:50  9   Travel
29/10/2015 6:15:51  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:52  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:53  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:54  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:55  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:56  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:57  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:58  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:15:59  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:00  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:01  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:02  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:03  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:04  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:05  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:06  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:07  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:08  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:09  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:10  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:11  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:12  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:13  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:14  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:15  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:16  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:17  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:18  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:19  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:20  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:21  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:22  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:23  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:24  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:25  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:26  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:27  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:28  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:29  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:30  9   Burst
29/10/2015 6:16:31  9   Burst
29/10/2015 6:16:32  9   Burst
29/10/2015 6:16:33  9   Burst
29/10/2015 6:16:34  9   Burst
29/10/2015 6:16:35  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:36  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:37  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:38  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:39  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:40  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:41  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:42  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:43  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:44  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:45  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:46  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:47  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:48  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:49  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:50  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:51  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:52  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:53  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:54  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:55  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:56  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:57  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:58  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:16:59  9   Low.energy.swimming
29/10/2015 6:17:00  9   Low.energy.swimming
```

I have seven behaviours and a big data set. I was thinking a loop may be the way to go but I don't have any experience with loops so would love your assistance with this!

Thank you!
Edit link for the data
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiQXB4O4k-d3gZ47Ns566Yw4TAGwtg?e=rVPuaR

Current table output for @joe springs code - these values are inncorect

```
Ascending   15.33061889
Burst   5.75
Descending  16.76580796
High.energy.swimming    149596.6434
Low.energy.swimming 57.8042349
Medium.energy.swimming  14.39765701
Travel  17.38504452
```

Comment: Are the rows all snapshot moments, where a "duration" is the total time elapsed until the next snapshot with a different activity? What does the `9` column represent? Are these all related to one individual? What does "massive" mean -- 100,000 rows, 10M, 1B?   This looks doable in base R using `aggregate`. I would usually use `dplyr`'s group_by & summarize to get your stats. If more than 100,000 individuals, `data.table` will be faster.

Comment: Duration is the total time elapsed until the next activity. 
Shark ID is '9' I have 20 sharks each with a unique ID in one data sheet it is 1760355 rows (massive may have been an overstatement but it is big)
I was thinking a loop being like: row above is x behaviour, keep going till row below changes to a different behaviour, then calculate duration of behaviour, calculating average duration at the end.

Comment: I can't open the data file in my browser since it is exceeding 25MB is size.  Can you cut it down to maybe six IDs and repost?

Comment: Thank you. This is one of the smaller IDs the rest were far to big for 25MB https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiQXB4O4k-d3gZ5X5fROkesgmXzrxQ?e=MIsd7N

Answer (score 0):

This solution has three basic steps.

1. Get the data grouped by activity_line_no. Basically, any time the activity changes per ID, you add a new a new line number. This is discussed really well here [Identify value change (categorical) by group. R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150092/identify-value-change-categorical-by-group-r)
2. Compute the durations by line number. I like `lubridate` for this.
3. Use `dplyr` to get the overall summary means and std errorr.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df_grouped<-df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(
    change = case_when(
      activity != lag(activity) ~ TRUE,
      TRUE ~ FALSE
    ),
    activity_line_no = cumsum(change)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(date_time, ID, activity, activity_line_no) 

df_grouped
#> # A tibble: 442 × 4
#>    date_time          ID    activity            activity_line_no
#>    <chr>              <chr> <chr>                          <int>
#>  1 29/10/2015 6:09:39 9     Low.energy.swimming                0
#>  2 29/10/2015 6:09:40 9     Low.energy.swimming                0
#>  3 29/10/2015 6:09:41 9     Low.energy.swimming                0
#>  4 29/10/2015 6:09:42 9     Low.energy.swimming                0
#>  5 29/10/2015 6:09:43 9     Low.energy.swimming                0
#>  6 29/10/2015 6:09:44 9     Travel                             1
#>  7 29/10/2015 6:09:45 9     Travel                             1
#>  8 29/10/2015 6:09:46 9     Travel                             1
#>  9 29/10/2015 6:09:47 9     Travel                             1
#> 10 29/10/2015 6:09:48 9     Travel                             1
#> # … with 432 more rows

df_durations<-df_grouped %>%
  group_by(ID, activity_line_no, activity) %>%
  summarize(first_time_stamp=first(date_time), 
            last_time_stamp=last(date_time),
            duration= ((dmy_hms(first_time_stamp) %--% dmy_hms(last_time_stamp)) %>% as.duration)/dseconds(1)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

df_durations
#> # A tibble: 11 × 6
#>    ID    activity_line_no activity    first_time_stamp  last_time_stamp duration
#>    <chr>            <int> <chr>       <chr>             <chr>              <dbl>
#>  1 9                    0 Low.energy… 29/10/2015 6:09:… 29/10/2015 6:0…        4
#>  2 9                    1 Travel      29/10/2015 6:09:… 29/10/2015 6:0…        7
#>  3 9                    2 Low.energy… 29/10/2015 6:09:… 29/10/2015 6:1…       45
#>  4 9                    3 Burst       29/10/2015 6:10:… 29/10/2015 6:1…        4
#>  5 9                    4 Low.energy… 29/10/2015 6:10:… 29/10/2015 6:1…      230
#>  6 9                    5 Burst       29/10/2015 6:14:… 29/10/2015 6:1…        5
#>  7 9                    6 Low.energy… 29/10/2015 6:14:… 29/10/2015 6:1…       65
#>  8 9                    7 Travel      29/10/2015 6:15:… 29/10/2015 6:1…        4
#>  9 9                    8 Low.energy… 29/10/2015 6:15:… 29/10/2015 6:1…       38
#> 10 9                    9 Burst       29/10/2015 6:16:… 29/10/2015 6:1…        4
#> 11 9                   10 Low.energy… 29/10/2015 6:16:… 29/10/2015 6:1…       25

df_summary <-df_durations %>%
  group_by(ID, activity) %>%
  summarize(n=n(),mean=mean(duration), stderr=sd(duration)/sqrt(n())) %>%
  ungroup()

df_summary
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   ID    activity                n  mean stderr
#>   <chr> <chr>               <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 9     Burst                   3  4.33  0.333
#> 2 9     Low.energy.swimming     6 67.8  33.5  
#> 3 9     Travel                  2  5.5   1.5


df<-structure(list(date_time = c("29/10/2015 6:09:39", "29/10/2015 6:09:40", 
"29/10/2015 6:09:41", "29/10/2015 6:09:42", "29/10/2015 6:09:43", 
"29/10/2015 6:09:44", "29/10/2015 6:09:45", "29/10/2015 6:09:46", 
"29/10/2015 6:09:47", "29/10/2015 6:09:48", "29/10/2015 6:09:49", 
"29/10/2015 6:09:50", "29/10/2015 6:09:51", "29/10/2015 6:09:52", 
"29/10/2015 6:09:53", "29/10/2015 6:09:54", "29/10/2015 6:09:55", 
"29/10/2015 6:09:56", "29/10/2015 6:09:57", "29/10/2015 6:09:58", 
"29/10/2015 6:09:59", "29/10/2015 6:10:00", "29/10/2015 6:10:01", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:02", "29/10/2015 6:10:03", "29/10/2015 6:10:04", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:05", "29/10/2015 6:10:06", "29/10/2015 6:10:07", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:08", "29/10/2015 6:10:09", "29/10/2015 6:10:10", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:11", "29/10/2015 6:10:12", "29/10/2015 6:10:13", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:14", "29/10/2015 6:10:15", "29/10/2015 6:10:16", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:17", "29/10/2015 6:10:18", "29/10/2015 6:10:19", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:20", "29/10/2015 6:10:21", "29/10/2015 6:10:22", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:23", "29/10/2015 6:10:24", "29/10/2015 6:10:25", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:26", "29/10/2015 6:10:27", "29/10/2015 6:10:28", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:29", "29/10/2015 6:10:30", "29/10/2015 6:10:31", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:32", "29/10/2015 6:10:33", "29/10/2015 6:10:34", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:35", "29/10/2015 6:10:36", "29/10/2015 6:10:37", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:38", "29/10/2015 6:10:39", "29/10/2015 6:10:40", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:41", "29/10/2015 6:10:42", "29/10/2015 6:10:43", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:44", "29/10/2015 6:10:45", "29/10/2015 6:10:46", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:47", "29/10/2015 6:10:48", "29/10/2015 6:10:49", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:50", "29/10/2015 6:10:51", "29/10/2015 6:10:52", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:53", "29/10/2015 6:10:54", "29/10/2015 6:10:55", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:56", "29/10/2015 6:10:57", "29/10/2015 6:10:58", 
"29/10/2015 6:10:59", "29/10/2015 6:11:00", "29/10/2015 6:11:01", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:02", "29/10/2015 6:11:03", "29/10/2015 6:11:04", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:05", "29/10/2015 6:11:06", "29/10/2015 6:11:07", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:08", "29/10/2015 6:11:09", "29/10/2015 6:11:10", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:11", "29/10/2015 6:11:12", "29/10/2015 6:11:13", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:14", "29/10/2015 6:11:15", "29/10/2015 6:11:16", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:17", "29/10/2015 6:11:18", "29/10/2015 6:11:19", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:20", "29/10/2015 6:11:21", "29/10/2015 6:11:22", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:23", "29/10/2015 6:11:24", "29/10/2015 6:11:25", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:26", "29/10/2015 6:11:27", "29/10/2015 6:11:28", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:29", "29/10/2015 6:11:30", "29/10/2015 6:11:31", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:32", "29/10/2015 6:11:33", "29/10/2015 6:11:34", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:35", "29/10/2015 6:11:36", "29/10/2015 6:11:37", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:38", "29/10/2015 6:11:39", "29/10/2015 6:11:40", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:41", "29/10/2015 6:11:42", "29/10/2015 6:11:43", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:44", "29/10/2015 6:11:45", "29/10/2015 6:11:46", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:47", "29/10/2015 6:11:48", "29/10/2015 6:11:49", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:50", "29/10/2015 6:11:51", "29/10/2015 6:11:52", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:53", "29/10/2015 6:11:54", "29/10/2015 6:11:55", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:56", "29/10/2015 6:11:57", "29/10/2015 6:11:58", 
"29/10/2015 6:11:59", "29/10/2015 6:12:00", "29/10/2015 6:12:01", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:02", "29/10/2015 6:12:03", "29/10/2015 6:12:04", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:05", "29/10/2015 6:12:06", "29/10/2015 6:12:07", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:08", "29/10/2015 6:12:09", "29/10/2015 6:12:10", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:11", "29/10/2015 6:12:12", "29/10/2015 6:12:13", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:14", "29/10/2015 6:12:15", "29/10/2015 6:12:16", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:17", "29/10/2015 6:12:18", "29/10/2015 6:12:19", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:20", "29/10/2015 6:12:21", "29/10/2015 6:12:22", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:23", "29/10/2015 6:12:24", "29/10/2015 6:12:25", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:26", "29/10/2015 6:12:27", "29/10/2015 6:12:28", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:29", "29/10/2015 6:12:30", "29/10/2015 6:12:31", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:32", "29/10/2015 6:12:33", "29/10/2015 6:12:34", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:35", "29/10/2015 6:12:36", "29/10/2015 6:12:37", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:38", "29/10/2015 6:12:39", "29/10/2015 6:12:40", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:41", "29/10/2015 6:12:42", "29/10/2015 6:12:43", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:44", "29/10/2015 6:12:45", "29/10/2015 6:12:46", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:47", "29/10/2015 6:12:48", "29/10/2015 6:12:49", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:50", "29/10/2015 6:12:51", "29/10/2015 6:12:52", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:53", "29/10/2015 6:12:54", "29/10/2015 6:12:55", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:56", "29/10/2015 6:12:57", "29/10/2015 6:12:58", 
"29/10/2015 6:12:59", "29/10/2015 6:13:00", "29/10/2015 6:13:01", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:02", "29/10/2015 6:13:03", "29/10/2015 6:13:04", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:05", "29/10/2015 6:13:06", "29/10/2015 6:13:07", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:08", "29/10/2015 6:13:09", "29/10/2015 6:13:10", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:11", "29/10/2015 6:13:12", "29/10/2015 6:13:13", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:14", "29/10/2015 6:13:15", "29/10/2015 6:13:16", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:17", "29/10/2015 6:13:18", "29/10/2015 6:13:19", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:20", "29/10/2015 6:13:21", "29/10/2015 6:13:22", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:23", "29/10/2015 6:13:24", "29/10/2015 6:13:25", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:26", "29/10/2015 6:13:27", "29/10/2015 6:13:28", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:29", "29/10/2015 6:13:30", "29/10/2015 6:13:31", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:32", "29/10/2015 6:13:33", "29/10/2015 6:13:34", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:35", "29/10/2015 6:13:36", "29/10/2015 6:13:37", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:38", "29/10/2015 6:13:39", "29/10/2015 6:13:40", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:41", "29/10/2015 6:13:42", "29/10/2015 6:13:43", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:44", "29/10/2015 6:13:45", "29/10/2015 6:13:46", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:47", "29/10/2015 6:13:48", "29/10/2015 6:13:49", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:50", "29/10/2015 6:13:51", "29/10/2015 6:13:52", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:53", "29/10/2015 6:13:54", "29/10/2015 6:13:55", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:56", "29/10/2015 6:13:57", "29/10/2015 6:13:58", 
"29/10/2015 6:13:59", "29/10/2015 6:14:00", "29/10/2015 6:14:01", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:02", "29/10/2015 6:14:03", "29/10/2015 6:14:04", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:05", "29/10/2015 6:14:06", "29/10/2015 6:14:07", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:08", "29/10/2015 6:14:09", "29/10/2015 6:14:10", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:11", "29/10/2015 6:14:12", "29/10/2015 6:14:13", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:14", "29/10/2015 6:14:15", "29/10/2015 6:14:16", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:17", "29/10/2015 6:14:18", "29/10/2015 6:14:19", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:20", "29/10/2015 6:14:21", "29/10/2015 6:14:22", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:23", "29/10/2015 6:14:24", "29/10/2015 6:14:25", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:26", "29/10/2015 6:14:27", "29/10/2015 6:14:28", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:29", "29/10/2015 6:14:30", "29/10/2015 6:14:31", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:32", "29/10/2015 6:14:33", "29/10/2015 6:14:34", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:35", "29/10/2015 6:14:36", "29/10/2015 6:14:37", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:38", "29/10/2015 6:14:39", "29/10/2015 6:14:40", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:41", "29/10/2015 6:14:42", "29/10/2015 6:14:43", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:44", "29/10/2015 6:14:45", "29/10/2015 6:14:46", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:47", "29/10/2015 6:14:48", "29/10/2015 6:14:49", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:50", "29/10/2015 6:14:51", "29/10/2015 6:14:52", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:53", "29/10/2015 6:14:54", "29/10/2015 6:14:55", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:56", "29/10/2015 6:14:57", "29/10/2015 6:14:58", 
"29/10/2015 6:14:59", "29/10/2015 6:15:00", "29/10/2015 6:15:01", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:02", "29/10/2015 6:15:03", "29/10/2015 6:15:04", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:05", "29/10/2015 6:15:06", "29/10/2015 6:15:07", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:08", "29/10/2015 6:15:09", "29/10/2015 6:15:10", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:11", "29/10/2015 6:15:12", "29/10/2015 6:15:13", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:14", "29/10/2015 6:15:15", "29/10/2015 6:15:16", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:17", "29/10/2015 6:15:18", "29/10/2015 6:15:19", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:20", "29/10/2015 6:15:21", "29/10/2015 6:15:22", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:23", "29/10/2015 6:15:24", "29/10/2015 6:15:25", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:26", "29/10/2015 6:15:27", "29/10/2015 6:15:28", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:29", "29/10/2015 6:15:30", "29/10/2015 6:15:31", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:32", "29/10/2015 6:15:33", "29/10/2015 6:15:34", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:35", "29/10/2015 6:15:36", "29/10/2015 6:15:37", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:38", "29/10/2015 6:15:39", "29/10/2015 6:15:40", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:41", "29/10/2015 6:15:42", "29/10/2015 6:15:43", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:44", "29/10/2015 6:15:45", "29/10/2015 6:15:46", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:47", "29/10/2015 6:15:48", "29/10/2015 6:15:49", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:50", "29/10/2015 6:15:51", "29/10/2015 6:15:52", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:53", "29/10/2015 6:15:54", "29/10/2015 6:15:55", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:56", "29/10/2015 6:15:57", "29/10/2015 6:15:58", 
"29/10/2015 6:15:59", "29/10/2015 6:16:00", "29/10/2015 6:16:01", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:02", "29/10/2015 6:16:03", "29/10/2015 6:16:04", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:05", "29/10/2015 6:16:06", "29/10/2015 6:16:07", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:08", "29/10/2015 6:16:09", "29/10/2015 6:16:10", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:11", "29/10/2015 6:16:12", "29/10/2015 6:16:13", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:14", "29/10/2015 6:16:15", "29/10/2015 6:16:16", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:17", "29/10/2015 6:16:18", "29/10/2015 6:16:19", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:20", "29/10/2015 6:16:21", "29/10/2015 6:16:22", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:23", "29/10/2015 6:16:24", "29/10/2015 6:16:25", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:26", "29/10/2015 6:16:27", "29/10/2015 6:16:28", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:29", "29/10/2015 6:16:30", "29/10/2015 6:16:31", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:32", "29/10/2015 6:16:33", "29/10/2015 6:16:34", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:35", "29/10/2015 6:16:36", "29/10/2015 6:16:37", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:38", "29/10/2015 6:16:39", "29/10/2015 6:16:40", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:41", "29/10/2015 6:16:42", "29/10/2015 6:16:43", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:44", "29/10/2015 6:16:45", "29/10/2015 6:16:46", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:47", "29/10/2015 6:16:48", "29/10/2015 6:16:49", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:50", "29/10/2015 6:16:51", "29/10/2015 6:16:52", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:53", "29/10/2015 6:16:54", "29/10/2015 6:16:55", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:56", "29/10/2015 6:16:57", "29/10/2015 6:16:58", 
"29/10/2015 6:16:59", "29/10/2015 6:17:00"), ID = c("9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9"), activity = c("Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Travel", "Travel", "Travel", "Travel", 
"Travel", "Travel", "Travel", "Travel", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Burst", "Burst", "Burst", "Burst", "Burst", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Burst", "Burst", 
"Burst", "Burst", "Burst", "Burst", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Travel", "Travel", "Travel", "Travel", 
"Travel", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Burst", "Burst", "Burst", "Burst", "Burst", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", "Low.energy.swimming", 
"Low.energy.swimming")), row.names = c(NA, -442L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure it has worked correctly, some of my values seem okay but then mean duration seems very low for some of my longest performed behaviours. - what unit is the mean in?

Comment: The mean is in minutes. You can change it by changing dminutes to dseconds

Comment: Yeah the values that I am getting are definitely wrong - mean (seconds)
`Ascending 15.33061889
Burst 5.75
Descending 16.76580796
High.energy.swimming 149596.6434
Low.energy.swimming 57.8042349
Medium.energy.swimming 14.39765701
Travel 17.38504452` 

Most of these behaviors should be occurring for minutes and even hours.  whislt the duration for high.energy.swiming should be much less.

Comment: `change = case_when(activity != lag(activity) ~ TRUE, TRUE ~ FALSE)`  would be simpler to code with `change = activity != lag(activity)`

Comment: using this new code, activity != lag(activity) give NA for the first row. I like your code. Is there a way to set the default?

Comment: The code isn't counting the activity_line_no properly. for example burst occurs three times but the script is counting it as two - It isn't doing it for all lines though mostly the shorter ones

Comment: hi @Sharklady I reposted my solution with the data i used. I also added the count to the final table. I am counting 3 burst groups. Try running the code with the data I included and see if this is what you are looking for. If so please consider accepting this answer...

Comment: Hi Joe thank you for your help. I have attached my data file as I still don't think these results are correct. as it is telling me that one of the behaviours is occurring for 48 hours. Also in the summary I only need this information for behaviour not per shark, I changed this in my script but shouldn't impact the results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.  If we assume each line of the logs is equal to 1 second, we can skip calculating the durations and just count the number of repeats per activity.  R has the `rle()` function for that.

```
#find the run lengths
runlengths <-rle(df$V4)
idruns <- rle(df$V3)

#place the count and labels into a data frame
rundf <-data.frame(runs=runlengths$lengths, values=runlengths$values)

library(dplyr)
#Summarize the data
answer <- rundf %>% group_by(values) %>% summarize(mean_in_sec=mean(runs), stderr=sd(runs)/sqrt(n()))
answer

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  values              mean_in_sec stderr
  <chr>                     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Burst                      5.33  0.333
2 Low.energy.swimming       69    33.4  
3 Travel                     6.5   1.5
```

The numbers above are very similar to Joe's solution.